# Why do I get result as unordered list instead of ordered list?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

So I have my code here that was supposed to produce an ordered list for every array of objects but instead it shows result as bullets as in unordered list and I don't understand which part went wrong as I used `<ol>` instead of `<ul>`. Please help!

```js
function onloadFunction() {
  var properties = [{
      unitNo: "C-8-1",
      owner: "Foo Yoke Wai"
    },
    {
      unitNo: "C-3A-3A",
      owner: "Chia Kim Hooi"
    },
    {
      unitNo: "B-18-8",
      owner: "Heng Tee See"
    },
    {
      unitNo: "A-10-10",
      owner: "Tang So Ny"
    },
    {
      unitNo: "B-19-10",
      owner: "Tang Xiao Mi"
    },
  ];

  var idk = document.getElementById("wrapper");
  var myList = "<ol>";
  for (var i = 0; i < properties.length; i++) {
    wrapper.innerHTML += "<li>" + properties[i].unitNo + ": " + properties[i].owner + "</li>";
  }
  myList += "</ol>";
}
```

```html
<html>

<body onload="onloadFunction()">

  <head></head>
  <div id="wrapper"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The structure defined by myList with the `<ol>` elements is never actually added to the document. If you concatenate the `<ol>`, then the `<li>` entries, then `</ol>` all to wrapper.innerHTML then it should work.

For example something like...

```
  var myList = "<ol>";
  for (var i = 0; i < properties.length; i++) {
    myList += "<li>" + properties[i].unitNo + ": " + properties[i].owner + "</li>";
  }
  myList += "</ol>";
  wrapper.innerHTML = myList;
```

Comment: Just a quick addition to this: if you use devtools to look at the resulting DOM, you can see that `<li>` elements reside directly in `<div id="wrapper">`, and the problem becomes obvious. I mean, inspecting real DOM might be very helpful to debug your code.

Answer (score 1):

If you would check your structure in dev tools you would see there was no `ol` element in finale result.
So you can create it:

```
var myList = document.createElement("ol");
```

Then fill it with `li`:

```
 myList.innerHTML
```

And then insert it:

```
idk.insertAdjacentElement("afterbegin", myList);
```

```js
function onloadFunction() {
  var properties = [{
      unitNo: "C-8-1",
      owner: "Foo Yoke Wai"
    },
    {
      unitNo: "C-3A-3A",
      owner: "Chia Kim Hooi"
    },
    {
      unitNo: "B-18-8",
      owner: "Heng Tee See"
    },
    {
      unitNo: "A-10-10",
      owner: "Tang So Ny"
    },
    {
      unitNo: "B-19-10",
      owner: "Tang Xiao Mi"
    },
  ];

  var idk = document.getElementById("wrapper");
  var myList = document.createElement("ol"); 
  for (var i = 0; i < properties.length; i++) {
    myList.innerHTML += "<li>" + properties[i].unitNo + ": " + properties[i].owner + "</li>";
  }
  idk.insertAdjacentElement("afterbegin", myList);
}
```

```html
<html>

<body onload="onloadFunction()">

  <head></head>
  <div id="wrapper"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop first then place the concatenated value into the wrapper...

If you look closely at your code when you inspect the parsed code in the browser inspector, you'll see that only the list items make it into the code. Then look at your myList variable, you never add that to the DOM. So by concatenating the variable and then adding it once you have  the entire string added, you'll get the ordered list parent elements as they are intended.

```js
function onloadFunction() {
  var properties = [{
      unitNo: "C-8-1",
      owner: "Foo Yoke Wai"
    },
    {
      unitNo: "C-3A-3A",
      owner: "Chia Kim Hooi"
    },
    {
      unitNo: "B-18-8",
      owner: "Heng Tee See"
    },
    {
      unitNo: "A-10-10",
      owner: "Tang So Ny"
    },
    {
      unitNo: "B-19-10",
      owner: "Tang Xiao Mi"
    },
  ];

  var idk = document.getElementById("wrapper");
  var myList = "<ol>";
  for (var i = 0; i < properties.length; i++) {
    myList += "<li>" + properties[i].unitNo + ": " + properties[i].owner + "</li>";
    
  }
  myList += "</ol>";
  
  wrapper.innerHTML = myList;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body onload="onloadFunction()">

  <head></head>
  <div id="wrapper"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is adding the innerHTML of `wrapper` directly as a `list`. You need to concat your data into `li` that will concat with your `ol` and at last add in DOM.

```js
function onloadFunction() {
  var properties = [{
      unitNo: "C-8-1",
      owner: "Foo Yoke Wai"
    },
    {
      unitNo: "C-3A-3A",
      owner: "Chia Kim Hooi"
    },
    {
      unitNo: "B-18-8",
      owner: "Heng Tee See"
    },
    {
      unitNo: "A-10-10",
      owner: "Tang So Ny"
    },
    {
      unitNo: "B-19-10",
      owner: "Tang Xiao Mi"
    },
  ];

  var idk = document.getElementById("wrapper");
  var myList = "<ol>";
  for (var i = 0; i < properties.length; i++) {
    myList += "<li>" + properties[i].unitNo + ": " + properties[i].owner + "</li>";
  }
  myList += "</ol>";
  wrapper.innerHTML = myList;
}

window.onload = onloadFunction;
```

```html
<div id="wrapper"></div>
```